# How to create custom post type visually?

Tags: wordpress

Can there is any wordpress plug-in that create custom post type visually without writing php, html, js etc code
Like 
Student
    Staid     int
    StdName varchar
    StdAddress varchar
It also provides CRUD functionality and also searching and etc...
If you are familiyer with drupal then it is almost same as new Content type but this is not available in Word press

Answer (score 0):

Always do some search before asking, you can use [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). It was on top of [Google search results](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=custom+post+type+plugin)